# How to add specific class or id to Radio button generated by simple_form association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

How can I add custom class to each radio button generated by f.association

```
 <%= f.association :sub_event, collection: @event.sub_events.in_stock, checked:  as: :radio_buttons, :input_html => { :onclick => "subEventFunction()"}, :item_wrapper_class => 'test_class' %>
```

:item_wrapper_class => 'test_class' adds this to each radio button, but I need to check a sub_event parameter and assign a different class or ID.

Final objective is to show/hide a div based on the radio button selection.

Answer (score 0):

What about a Jquery that change the class if it is not == 1 ,
like

```
count class X 
if class x amount == 1 then nothing
else select first change to XZY+1+var
loop until amount == 1
```